# Where is Luke 24:47 referenced in the Old Testament?

Tags: old-testament, gospel-of-luke, words-of-jesus, intertextuality

According to Luke 24:47. Jesus says "it is written" that "...repentance and remission of sins should be preached in his name"

Where, in the Old Testament, the allusion that **specifically** mentions "repentance and remission of sins" and about them being preached?

Luke 24:45-48 (KJV):

> <sup>45</sup> Then opened he their understanding, that they might understand the scriptures,
> <sup>46</sup> And said unto them, Thus it is written, and thus it behooved Christ to suffer, and to rise from the dead the third day:
> <sup>47</sup> And that repentance and remission of sins should be preached in his name among all nations, beginning at Jerusalem.
> <sup>48</sup> And ye are witnesses of these things.

Comment: There is a similar question on the companion site: [Where is what Luke 24:46, 1Cor 15:4 states written in Heb Bible that Christ would rise from the dead on the Third Day? - Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/49516/where-is-what-luke-2446-1cor-154-states-written-in-heb-bible-that-christ-woul).

Comment: This question belongs to [Biblical Hermeneutics SE](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/).